# How to use malloc in this situation?

Tags: c

I'm a bit of a newbie at C, so please bear with me...

I have a function to count char in a string called `char strLength`, but I have to create a function that uses this function to count the number of characters in a passed string, mallocates a new string with space for a NULL terminator, copies the string and then returns the copy.

Here's what I have:

character counter

```
int strLength(char* toCount)
{
    int count = 0;

    while(*toCount != '\0')
    {
        count++;
        toCount++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

and here's the beginning of the sought-after function

```
char* strCopy(char *s)
{
    int length = strLength(s);

}
```

Comment: I'm really struggling on how to use malloc

Comment: I guess you didn't try looking at any of the 37,000 or so posts containing the keyword `malloc` under the C tag on this site... http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+malloc

Answer (score 1):

Since you are struggling with `malloc`, here is how the next line should look:

```
char* strCopy(char *s)
{
    int length = strLength(s);
    char *res = malloc(length+1);
    // Copy s into res; stop when you reach '\0'
    ...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: @user3089390 No, that would create a memory leal. The next line should be [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) or [`memcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/memcpy.html). Alternatively, you could write your own loop that does copying. Don't forget to put the `'\0'` at the end of `res`.

Comment: Or, most likely, your own custom function to copy the bytes (since you had to implement `strlen`).

Comment: I don't understand how to add each character, would I treat it like an array? I feel I should try a while loop with the conditions (*s != '\0') but I feel that would be wrong...

Comment: And strcpy and memcpy cannot be used. I'm trying to just write my own function.

Comment: @user3089390 You can add each character by treating `s` and `res` like two arrays. You can stop after copying zero from the last position of `s` into `res`.

Answer (score 0):

You want `strdup`.  However, since I suspect this is a learning exercise:

```
char *strCopy(const char *src)
{
    size_t l = strlen(src) + 1;
    char *r = malloc(l);
    if (r)
       memcpy(r, src, l);
    return r;
}
```

If you are curious how to copy strings yourself, you could replace the `memcpy` with something like:

```
char *dst = r;
while (*src)
   *dst++ = *src++;
*dst = 0;
```

However I would suggest using library functions: if not `strdup`, then `malloc` + `memcpy`.

Comment: I appreciate it, but memcpy is out of my range of knowledge

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use strdup() clib call.
2. You can write something like:

> ```
> char* strCopy(char *s) {
>   int length = strLength(s);
>   char *rc = (char *)malloc(length + 1);
>   return rc? strcpy(rc, s) : NULL;
> }
> ```